# make the video on the center of the page

Tags: css

how can i make the video on my website on the center of the page ??

http://al-moltazem.com/

```css
.wp-video-shortcode video, video.wp-video-shortcode {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.mejs-mediaelement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You should google ***"research effort"***.

Comment: If the answer below answered your question, please mark as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding margin to the wp-video class

```
 .wp-video
 {   
 margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

Comment: [Not working](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/n4kxy8LL/)...

Comment: The parent div is 100% width already on his page, so it does works. Put a 100% width container around the div that he wants centered.